# IF statement not going to ELSE

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Can I get some help, please?
The if statement is not going to else condition.
Also, the reverse, if I change `($data == $data1)` simply will skip if statement and jump directly to else.

Please see my code below:

```php
include 'detalii.php';

$con = mysqli_connect("192.168.1.11","test","","admin");

$check = "SELECT ID FROM `q7f6xr` where VIRTUALM = 'REGO-A' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1 ";
$check1 = "SELECT CHEIE FROM `rego-a` ORDER BY CHEIE DESC LIMIT 1";

$rs = mysqli_query($con, $check);
$rs1 = mysqli_query($con, $check1);

$data = mysqli_fetch_array($rs);
$data1 = mysqli_fetch_array($rs1);

if ($data != $data1) {
    // DACA IP-UL EXISTA EXECUTA AICI
    // IF IP EXISTS EXECUTE THIS
    echo "IP-ul exista deja !<br/>";
} else {
    $newUser = "INSERT INTO `rego-a` (`CHEIE`) VALUES ('$data[0]')";
    if (mysqli_query($con, $newUser)) {
        // DACA IP E UNIC EXECUTA AICI
        // IF IP IS UNIQUE EXECUTE THIS
        echo exec('C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test1.txt');
        echo "You are now registered<br/>";
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: Well, they're obviously not the same. Have you tried `var_dump()`-ing them?

Comment: have you tried to print message in your if else condition to get to know ??

Comment: The vars `$data` and `$data1` are always unequal, so The `else` condition is never executed. Try `var_dump()` in `if` statement and make sure the vars are the same, maybe a little difference in output.

Another test you can do is to view in db if the query actually produces equal results, maybe a mistake in query produce always different values.

Comment: You could just do the comparison in the SQL.. not that it would fix your issue but simplifies the code, and DB calls.

Answer (score 3):

Checking for equality on the return value of `mysqli_fetch_array` is not a good choice. These are arrays, and their equality depends on several considerations, making your code extremely brittle.

It would be better to check for equality using individual elements of these arrays. For example:

```
if ( $data[0] == $data1[0] )
{
    // Values are equal
}
else
{
    // Values are NOT equal
}
```

You can also use associative arrays with named indexes:

```
$data  = mysqli_fetch_array( $rs,  MYSQLI_ASSOC );
$data1 = mysqli_fetch_array( $rs1, MYSQLI_ASSOC );

if ( $data["ID"] == $data1["CHEIE"] )
{
    // Values are equal
}
```